# Stuck on adding to an array

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

I am trying to write a method which adds a phone directory entry to theDirectory - an array which holds all my DirectoryEntrys. Each directory entry contains 2 strings, a name, and a telno.

I was given this pseudocode to point me in the right direction:

```
Algorithm for add 
 if size >= capacity 
 reallocate() 
 set theDirectory[size] to new DirectoryEntry(name, telno) 
 increment size
```

And this is what I came up with, however I get an error in the constructor of my new DirectoryEntry, stating it cannot find symbol, for neither name nor telno. Any help towards solving the problem would be much appreciated!

My Code:

```
private void add() {
    if (size >= capacity)
    {
        reallocate();
    }
    theDirectory[size] = new DirectoryEntry(name, telno);
    size = size +1;
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Seems like you need to initialize name and telno inside the function or pass them as arguments.

For example:

```
String name = "Joe Perkins";
String telno = "0000-00-00-00";
```

You probably want them as arguments, something like:

```
private void add(String name, String telno) {
    // rest of the code here
}
```

Comment: @JoePerkins You should mark the question as solved then. Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the name and telno to the add method as parameters.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @FallenAngel Why do you think that this is not (at least an attempt to) an answer?

Comment: @MathiasMüller With an example code for demonstration, it would be an answer. In this form, that is more like a comment.

Comment: @FallenAngel It's a short answer, but it's an answer. The problem is that he isn't passing in the variables, he needs to add them as parameters. To learn he needs to find out what that means and do it himself, not just blindly copy code from an example. I've upvoted the other answer that did go into more detail but that didn't mean my answer was wrong.